# VS Code can't find header files In Linux VSCode

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

My **`workspace`** is :

```
├── README.md
└── sim
   ├── Makefile
   ├── include
   │   ├── add.cpp
   │   └── add.h
   │   
   └── src
       └── main.cpp
```

My **`main.cpp`** is :

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Add.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c;
    c = add(a, b);
    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My **`add.h`** is:

```
// Add.h
#include <iostream>
#include "main.cpp"
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b);
```

My **`add.cpp`** is:

```
//add.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Add.h"

using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

My **`c_cpp_properties.json`** is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/sim/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My **`launch.json`** is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "miDebuggerArgs": "-q -ex quit; wait() { fg >/dev/null; }; /bin/gdb -q --interpreter=mi",
            "name": "C/C++",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "compile",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My **`tasks.json`** is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/sim/include/**"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I encountered an error when I pressed F5 in  `main.cpp` :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sWwa.png)

```
 *  Executing task: g++ -g /home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main.cpp -o /home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main -I/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/include/** 

/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: Add.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "Add.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

 *  The terminal process "g++ '-g', '/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main.cpp', '-o', '/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main', '-I/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/include/**'" failed to launch (exit code: 1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

What should I do ?

How can I get my main.cpp and its header files to work together when they are in different folders? I am using Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL2 and connecting remotely via VSCode.

Comment: First of all, you don't need `**` after `-I`. Second, Linux filenames are case-sensitive: `Add.h` vs `add.h`.

Comment: You never want `**` in the `-I` command line switch, and I also advise against using `**` anywhere. List directories you need explicitly. Much fewer surprises this way.

Comment: @ n. m. could be an AI, Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you for your guidance, you're correct. Renaming "Add.h" to "add.h" resolved the squiggles issue. However, when I attempted to run main.cpp again, I encountered a new error: `"/home/chris/Code/graduation-project/sim/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to add(int, int)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status." `  Could there be any issues with the way my add.h` and add.cpp files are written? I'm quite new to C++ and still learning :(

Comment: Replace `"${file}",` with `"sim/src/main.cpp", "sim/include/add.cpp",` (btw, weird to have source files in `include/`). Might also want to replace `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` with a constant filename. You don't want the output name to depend on what file you have open (if you're writing a multifile program).

Comment: If your project really has a Makefile you can use it with the MakeFileTools extension: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools)

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat, It works! Thanks again for your help! It seems that the path setup is quite important when writing multifile C++ programs. Are there any standards for setting paths to prevent similar compilation errors? It seems quite cumbersome to add files every time haha.

Comment: You should start using a proper build system (Make, CMake, Meson are popular). Usually people are listing each .cpp file manually (in the script file for their build system), but most build systems can automatically grab every .cpp file in a directory.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem as is described by the first question.  Based on the discussion here I was able to get mine working.

What I find disconcerting (and confusing) is that the Intellisense Include path is maintained separately from the compiler's Include path.  The Include path in the c_cpp_properties.json seems to only affect Intellisense, whereas the compiler option -I is maintained in the tasks.json; the GUI interface doesn't automatically keep the two coordinated.  (Unless mine is broken.)  Also, there seems to be a difference in convention, where the /** works to recursively specify the include directory for the Intellisense, /* shuts off the recursion for the compiler option.  Or, at least that is what it appears for me.